# How to remove all spaces in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, web, filter, spaces

How to remove all spaces in an array? all kinds of spaces such as double space, tabs, whitespaces and etc...

I tried this but it only removes a single space.

```
array_filter( parse_ini_file( 'C:/xampp/htdocs/essentials/configuration.ini' ) )
```

Comment: you could try to `array_map` and `trip` the array, if its nested, you'll need to do it recursively

Answer (score 0):

For just spaces, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```